# MySQL permission denied for database

Tags: mysql

I have a remote MySQL server running on x.x.x.x. And there is a database named abc.

I can do the following

```
mysql -h x.x.x.x -uroot
use abc
```

But when I try to

```
mysql -h x.x.x.x -uroot --database=abc
```

I get

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'abc'
```

Why is that? And how do I fix it?

edit:

I have now resolved the issue by doing the following:

1. `ssh in the box`
2. `run mysql -uroot`
3. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

But I still don't understand why.

mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();

```
+-----------------------------+----------------+
| USER()                      | CURRENT_USER() |
+-----------------------------+----------------+
| root@Maxs-MacBook-Air.local | root@%         |
+-----------------------------+----------------+
```

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR root@'%';

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'                                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) from mysql.user WHERE user='root';
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'Maxs-MacBook-Air.local' for table 'user'
```

Max

Comment: Please run `mysql -h x.x.x.x -uroot`. When you get in, run `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and post that output.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Done!

Comment: Please run `SHOW GRANTS FOR root@'%';` and `SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) from mysql.user WHERE user='root';` and post them as well. (Please hide the encrypted password).

Comment: Done. And I got a permission denied error for the select statement. Somehow it ran as root@my-laptop.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Hi, seems I have resolved the issue. I manually ssh'ed into the box, and then run GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION and now I can do mysql -h x.x.x.x -uroot --database=abc. Still not sure why this is the case but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run

```
SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) from mysql.user WHERE user='root';
```

because you do not have remote rights to the `mysql` database.

You only have remote rights to `mydb`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

When you ran

```
mysql -h x.x.x.x -uroot --database=abc
```

you evidently do not have remote rights to database `abc`.

When you ran

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

you should now have rights to every database.

Comment: That makes sense, but how come I could access and modify database abc but doing a "mysql -h x.x.x.x -uroot" first then doing a "use abc"?

Comment: Did you actually run any SELECTs, INSERTs, UPDATEs, or DELETEs after you ran `use abc` ? Note that you ran `SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) from mysql.user WHERE user='root';` and it did not work. It should work now. When your grant was `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`, you were not restricted from running `use abc`. Once inside, you were restricted from running SELECTs, INSERTs, UPDATEs, or DELETEs.

Comment: Gotcha. Now that I think about it, I probably did all CRUD on that box rather than through remote access.